# fping using IP list in python3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, centos7, ping

I am new to python and I am trying to scan multiple IPs with fping. I have large number of server to monitor for statistics and I could write the following code that works for 2 hosts:

```
 
    import subprocess
    import binascii

    out = ''
    err = ''

    host1 = '172.2.2.5'
    host2 = '172.1.5.8'
    hosts = '/tmp/ip.list'

    ping = subprocess.Popen(['fping', '-C', '10', '-b', '50', '-p', '25', host1, host2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    try:             
        [out, err] = ping.communicate(timeout=15)

        print('STDOUT')
        print(out.decode('utf-8').strip())

        print('STDERR (Statistics)')
        print(err.decode('utf-8').strip())

    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print('STDERR (expired timeout)')
```

However, I am unable to replace the two hosts with list of host files, though I tried in multiple ways.

I would very much appreciate any help this regard or any improvements in the program itself.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple fix:

```
with open('ip_list.csv', 'r') as fh:
    all_ips = fh.read().splitlines()

cmd = ['fping', '-C', '10', '-b', '50', '-p', '25']
cmd.extend(all_ips)

ping = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```